# Secure connection between Windows 8 App and WCF rest service

Tags: wcf, ssl, azure, windows-8

I've got a WCF service hosted on Windows Azure and a Windows 8 app that currently consumes data from the rest based WCF service.

The service is hosted at abc.cloudapp.net and although currently anybody can access it, I'd like to limit access to users of my app only.

I can't ask users to enter a username and password and I also can't store encryption data in the app as I can't be sure that my Windows 8 App will be obfuscated.

SSL seems to be the only way to go - however the setup of the SSL certificate requires a CSR which I don't believe can be applied to a service hosted on azure.

I'm looking for a step by step guide to securing communication between the app and the service as well as preventing unauthorised access.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

REST service works with the HTTP standards. SSL is default mechanism to ensure data transfer with security. Authentication is an implementation question.

Two links to help you with development:

[SSL on Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff795779.aspx)

[REST based authentication](http://www.berenddeboer.net/rest/authentication.html)

Regards.

Comment: So how do I register the certificate? I end up with two certificates, one that relies on a public key and another that relies on a private key. Which one do I install where?